# Where clause in SQL query c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to write a SQL where clause in c#. I have grid which binds the data from DB. I have three Search panel at the top of the grid with 3 text boxes. Namely txtPartnumber, txtArticle, txtSmn. When I click the search button the grid should be filtered. 
E.x. Following are the filtering options for the grid.

1)Only the 'Partnumber' is provided for the search 
2)Only the 'Article Number' is provided for the search 
3)Only the 'SMN' is provided for the search 
4) 'Partnumber'  and 'SMN' is provided for the search etc..

To Filter the Data in Grid using a SQL squery i have tried the following code. The Where clause in the SQl seems to be hard to build. Attached my code and my code segment seems not the a best code with more complexity on it. How can I minimize the complexity and optimize my code with lesser lines on code.

```
private string getCondtionForSearch()
    {
        string condition = string.Empty;
        string whereCondition = " Where ";
        string andCondition = " AND ";
        string articleCondition = string.Empty;
        string partNumberCondition = string.Empty;
        string smnCondition = string.Empty;
        int condtitionCount = 0;

        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArticle.Text)))
        {
            articleCondition = string.Concat("ARTICLE = ", txtArticle.Text);
            condtitionCount++;
        }

        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPartnumber.Text)))
        {
            partNumberCondition = string.Concat("PART_NUMBER = ", txtPartnumber.Text);
            condtitionCount++;
        }

        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSmn.Text)))
        {
            smnCondition = string.Concat("SMN = ", txtSmn.Text);
            condtitionCount++;
        }

        if (condtitionCount == 0)
            condition = "SELECT * FROM [ItemMaster]";
        else
        {

            StringBuilder conditionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            conditionBuilder.Append(whereCondition);
            if (condtitionCount == 1)
            {
                conditionBuilder.Append(articleCondition);
                conditionBuilder.Append(partNumberCondition);
                conditionBuilder.Append(smnCondition);
            }
            if (condtitionCount == 2)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(articleCondition))
                {
                    conditionBuilder.Append(partNumberCondition);
                    conditionBuilder.Append(andCondition);
                    conditionBuilder.Append(smnCondition);
                }          

            }


            conditionBuilder.Append(andCondition);

            condition = conditionBuilder.ToString();


        }

        return condition;
    }
```

Appreciate your helps on this.

Comment: Rather do it at the front end.

Comment: What do you want sql query or the c# linq ? And try something yourself that way u understand a lot. Who knows you might dont need us.

Comment: Hi, I need a SQL query I tried as above to get the Where clause of a SQL query. But I feel its complex and not the optimum method.

Comment: And you might want to add the space after the each `And` like `SMN = `  should be `  SMN = `  so previous value dont get concat with column name.

Comment: So if I do like 'SMN=' if the value is null in a AND condition will it get the results? If so it is a simple solution for mine

Comment: I have noticed you are not including single quote while building query.

Comment: Yes Thanks I am applying it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is modified and simplified version of answer from Coder of Code

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [ItemMaster] Where 1 = 1 "

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArticle.Text))
{
    string.Concat(query ,"AND ARTICLE = @Article ");
    //add parameter value for @Article
} 
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPartnumber.Text))
{
    string.Concat(query ,"AND PART_NUMBER = @Part_Number ");
    //add parameter value for @Part_Number
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSmn.Text))
{
    string.Concat(query ,"AND SMN = @SMN ");
    //add parameter value for @SMN
}
return query;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to build the query this way then try this. And you should use the paramterzied query to avoid the possibility from `sql injection`.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [ItemMaster]"
string whereClause = string.empty;
bool andFlag = false;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArticle.Text))
{
    string temp = " ARTICLE = @Article";
    string.Concat(wherClause,temp);
    andFlag = true;
    //add parameter value for @Article
} 
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPartnumber.Text))
{
    string temp = string.Empty;
    if(andFlag)
         temp = " AND PART_NUMBER = @Part_Number";
    else 
        temp = " PART_NUMBER = @Part_Number";
    string.Concat(whereClause ,temp);
    //add parameter value for @Part_Number
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSmn.Text))
{
    string temp = string.Empty;
    if(andFlag)
         temp = " AND SMN = @SMN";
    else 
        temp = " SMN = @SMN";
    string.Concat(whereClause ,temp);
    //add parameter value for @SMN
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSmn.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPartnumber.Text) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArticle.Text))
   string.concat(query," WHERE ",whereClause);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. i need to have a AND condition in the where clause. I can be 2 and conditions or 1 Or even none. It the issue which I have

Comment: Any clue on building a AND condition on top of this..:(

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (didn't test it):

```
var sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM [ItemMaster]");

var whereClause = CheckFilter(txtArticle) + 
                CheckFilter(txtPartnumber) + 
                CheckFilter(txtSmn);

whereClause = whereClause.Substring(0, whereClause.Length - 5);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(whereClause.Trim())
{
    sql.AppendLine(" WHERE ");
    sql.AppendLine(whereClause);
}

// using the textbox Name property as the column name
private string CheckFilter(TextBox textbox)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text) 
        ? string.Format(" {0} = {1} AND ", textbox.Name, textbox.Text) 
        : string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your where clause simple by checking each value: See code (but change it to use StringBuilder, and change it also to use parameters)

```
private string getCondtionForSearch()
    {
        string condition = string.Empty;
        string whereCondition = string.Empty;

        // TODO same for all values
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArticle.Text)))
        {
            whereCondition = whereCondition + '"ARTICLE = "' + txtArticle.Text + " AND ";
        }

        // TODO 1: cut last 5 chars (" AND ")
        // TODO 2: Add " WHERE " at the begin
        // TODO 3: Add whereCondition to your SQL 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(whereCondition))
        {

        }
        return condition;
    }
```

BUT: Your code is vulnerable by SQL Injection, so Change this to use SQL Parameters (Google)

Comment: Yes please. Question I have is Where clause can have multiple AND conditions or even now. need to handle it.

Comment: See my edited code: You have to do a lot for this, but it´s quite simple. You add ALL 'AND' Clauses (doesnt matter if there are non or 100 ...), check if ANY was added (not empty), cut the last " AND ", and add " WHERE " at the beginning of your where condition

Comment: The best way would be also, to change the function to return a complete SqlCommand, then you can fill your parameters with the @named parameters.

Comment: also see the even simpler way of Jenish Rabadiya - I voted him :-)

Comment: Yes thanks Thomas It is the simple way